# Broadcom driver issue with TP-Link Archer T6E AC1300 14.04

Tags: drivers, wireless

Having some issues getting driver installed properly for new wireless adapter. The adapter is a TP-Link Archer T6E AC 1300. Running ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I have followed this thread to get to where I am now: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

After I run: `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` I can see my wireless network. After typing in the network password it looks like I am connected, but do not have internet connection.

Upon reboot, I get error messages. The following messages are from the boot log and seem relevant

> loadndisdriver: loadndisdriver: load_driver(343): couldn't find valid
>   drivers files for driver bcmwl6
>
> loadndisdriver: loadndisdriver: load_driver(364): couldn't load driver
>   bcmwl6

Additionally, when I reboot I can no longer see any wireless networks until I run `sudo modprobe wl`. After running the command, the wireless networks show up. Same issue as above - I can connect to my network but have to internet.

Output from: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` is

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Limited Device [14e4:0619]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 02)
```

Comment: Edit the question to include results from terminal for `ndiswrapper -l`

Comment: It appears that you have bcmwl-kernel-source *AND* ndiswrapper installed and that they conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix may be to remove the ndiswrapper driver with

```
sudo ndiswrapper -r bcmwl6
```

But since it appears you may have deleted bcmwl6, you may need to

```
sudo apt-get purge ndiswrapper
```

Reboot

Comment: Thanks, I appear to be making some progress. I got rid of of ndiswrapper and now my network shows up upon re-boot, but still not getting internet. Not sure if this is a driver issue anymore. I noticed that after I purged ndiswrapper there was still a .conf file in /etc/modprobe.d. My wireless networks didn't show up until I deleted this file. Anywhere else that ndiswrapper might be hanging around on my system?

Comment: You may need to `sudo depmod -a` and can you ping anything after connecting. `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` or `ping -c3 google.com`

Comment: Issue is fixed. I had already run `sudo depmod -a` after purging ndiswrapper and deleting the .conf file. This morning, I rebooted again and now have wireless internet. Thanks for the help!